# Radical with underscript

Tags: spacing, underbrace, sqrt

How can I make the radical end at the same level with 11...1 and 44...4 and put the underbrace below the radical?
I have this:
`\sqrt{ \underbrace{11...1}_n\underbrace{44...4}_{2n}}`

Comment: It is not clear what you want. maybe `\underbrace{\sqrt{}}`?

Comment: Something like this, but I have two separate underbarce under the same radical, and I need them to remain exactly below that numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert the `\sqrt` with `\phantom` content and then overlap the `\underbrace`d content using `\mathllap` (from [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
  \sqrt{\phantom{11 \cdots 1 \, 44 \cdots 4}}
  \mathllap{\underbrace{11 \cdots 1}_n\underbrace{44 \cdots 4}_{2n}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just for the sake of variety, here's a solution that uses `\smash[b]{...}` and `\vphantom` to achieve the typographic objective. The `\vphantom` directive serves to insert what's called a typographic strut, placed *outside* the square-root term.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\smash[b]{...}" macro
\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{\smash[b]{\underbrace{11...1}_n\underbrace{44...4}_{2n}}} \vphantom{\underbrace{1}_{n}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is how I'd do it, too.